# GIMP: Ellipse position from center

Tags: gimp

I know that I can create an ellipse from the center. However, inside the tool properties panel, "Position" refers to the top-left corner.

How could I change its position based on its center point? I want to locate it right on the center of the document.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps to center an elliptical selection in GIMP:

1. Make selection

   [image]
2. Create a **floating selection** <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
3. Select the floating selection (by mouse):

   [image]
4. Choose the **Alignment tool** [image]
5. Align the selected object *"Relative to Image"* by choosing

   - Distribute horizontal centers [image]
   - Distribute vertical centers [image]

   [image]